# Аналог system в ассемблерном коде

Tags: linux, c, ассемблер, x86-64, x86

Какой аналог system в ассемблерном коде? Например, чтобы вывести строку в stdout под linux x86 надо в eax записать номер системного вызова, в ebx записать код потока(для stdout это 1), в ecx указатель на строку, в edx длину строки. И потом вызвать прерывание(int 0x80). Итого:

```
  mov $4,   %eax
  mov $1,   %ebx
  mov $msg, %ecx
  mov $len, %edx
  int $0x80
```

Как в ассемблере написать аналог вызова C-шной функции system? Без разницы  под x86 или x64. Например, я хочу написать аналог для вызова system("gedit").

Answer (score 2):

Запуск файла на исполнение осуществляется через 11-ю функцию 80-го прерывания.
Вот на английском SO был вопрос про это: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342410/sys-execve-system-call-from-assembly